# how to reload table view after a specific time

Tags: swift, tableview

I have to call a api and when the api is call  I have to move on next controller and show a table with list of data but my problem is when I move  to next controller the api call is not finished yet so table view is become empty . Is there any way so that I can reload table view after a specific time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a completion handler of some sort when you do the API call. Make use of it!

You can either 1) show the table view after the API call has finished, or 2) show the table view first, then reload it once the API call has finished.

Pseudocode:

```
// 1)
showLoadingIndicator()
performAPICall(completion: { data, error in
    if error != nil {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "show table view", sender: data)
        // remember to pass the data in prepareForSegue
        hideLoadingIndicator()
    }
})

// or

// 2)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "show table view", sender: nil)

// in the table view controller,
performAPICall(completion: { data, error in
    if error != nil {
        self.data = data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do this by using DispatchTime.

```
let time =  DispatchTime.now() + 5
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
                // reload your table view here
            }
```

but for a good programming first, let your API call complete and then move to your next controller for that use completion handler.